# Cannot run VSCode on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, oraclelinux

I installed the latest VSCode on Linux (Oracle Linux, a variant of RedHat) and it gave the following symbol lookup error.  Any idea?

```
$ /usr/share/code/bin/code
/usr/share/code/bin/../code: symbol lookup error: /usr/share/code/bin/../code: undefined symbol: UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_SKIP_60
```

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the wrong libraries were dynamically linked. In particular, libnode and libffmpeg. After setting up the environment to point to the appropriate locations, it worked.